# about the number of rows affected to which transformation changes and view-tab changes in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I got a small concern in Power Query. When we make transformation changes and also changes in view-tab over columns in power query, would they apply to complete data in the view (of the model) or just a subset of data?

I tried to get some tips on this concern over google, but, didn't really help my attempt. Thank you for your support.

Comment: What kind of transformation?  Please show the applicable m code.  If you transform the data type of a column, it applies to the entire column. If you do other kinds of transformations, it depends on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Ron, Thank you for responding to my concern; well, my question is general sense; but, by your explanation, I understood that the scenario shall be specific to what I am trying to achieve;  is there any documentation source to understand the scenarios that you can recommend me?

Comment: By outlining a specific situation, it would help me to understand what you are trying to do (something I am not sure of now) and perhaps answer your question. I started learning PQ recently, and rely on MS documentation, user groups, and the numerous blogs that can be found on the internet. For me, I find it easier to go from a specific example to a more general discussion, than the other way around.

Comment: Got it... Thank you, Ron